# Always insert UTC datetime

Tags: node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js

I using **Sequelize** with **sqlite3** dialect and I having problem with inserting
DATE datatype. Sequelize always default "+0:00" whenever I tried to call model.create()
to a table even though I used "new Date()" or default "(DATETIME('NOW', 'LOCALTIME')" in column default. I would prefer I have time zone control or at least follow my local machine timezone.

Running on Node v16^

Comment: In SQLite there is no date/datetime data type. Functions like `DATETIME('NOW', 'LOCALTIME')` return strings in the ISO format like `'2022-06-30 16:17:23'` without the timezone. If you want to include the timezone you should format properly the dates in your app's code and insert in the table the formatted strings.

Comment: @forpas that's what im trying to as well. I even use momentjs to generate string format and tried to insert using sequelize. But in date column is always +0:00 even tho I formatted without it

Answer (score 0):

As best practices it would be better to have the dates saved in the database as utc without time zone and apply it directly from the application, with the necessary logic.
This allows you to manage the time zone and always know which is the standard.